# Number of Triples Between $1$ and $n$

Tags: combinatorics

The exact question is:

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find the number of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq n$ .

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: are you wanting all of the pythagorean triplets? or just three numbers that satisfy the above statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $b=k$, then there are $k$ possible values for $a$ (from $1$ to $k$) and $n-k+1$ values for $c$ (from $k$ to $n$). That makes a total of $k(n-k+1)$ possibilities for each value of $k$ from $1$ to $n$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n k(n-k+1) &= (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n k - \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}(n+1) - \frac{n(n+1)}{6}(2n+1)\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}{6}(3n+3-2n-1)\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}{6}(n+2)
\end{align}$$
(For the formulas used to solve the sums, check [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula))

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to start this kind of problem by doing some small number cases. If $n=1$ you have

1. 1,1,1

If n=2 you also have

2. 1,1,2
3. 1,2,2
4. 2,2,2

if n=3 you have all of the above plus

5. 1,1,3
6. 1,2,3
7. 1,3,3
8. 2,2,3
9. 2,3,3
10. 3,3,3

The sequence 1, 4, 10 is a good hint for the answer. See @Wood's answer for the full argument.

Answer (score 1):

Three is a very small number, so we can afford to do cases. (There is a more general approach using Stars and Bars.)

Case (i) The numbers are distinct. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ ways to choose them, and then only $1$ way to line them up in order.

Case(s) (ii) The smaller two are equal, and the third is bigger, or the smallest is unique, and there is a tie for biggest. We can pick $2$ numbers in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. Then double, for a total of $2\binom{n}{2}$.

Case (iii) All equal. There are $\binom{n}{1}$ choices.

Add up.